# Print the mongodb query for debug

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new one for the mongodb,i like to print the query for find the error on that, i search with google, but no result is related to my expectation.

```
 the query is
 -------------
    $this->mdb_obj = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.1.47:27017");
    $this->runboy_database = $this->mdb_obj->selectDB('runboy');
    $this->post = new MongoCollection($this->runboy_database, 'post');
    $result = $this->post->find(array("km" => array('$lt' => 5)));
```

so how can i debug the query ? your ideas and suggestion will help me more

Comment: The error where? There is only one like of "query" there, but where is your error occurring?

Comment: i like to find the error, for that how to print the query?. i want the query as like mysql query (select * from table_name ).

Comment: The query is exactly what you are sending, and the "query" is only what lies between the `->find()`. You have no variables here so nothing to debug. I ask again, what error? There can be no "query" error by the arguments used here so it can only be database connection.